# Migrating User to Cognito on Sign In

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I am trying to migrate users to Cognito when they sign in the first time. For this I wrote a lambda function that does call an API to check if the users exist in db or not ? if the user exists, it will be created in cognito but I am not sure how do I tell the application that user is created and it should allow the user to login .

Here is the code in c#:

```
    public async Task<Stream> FunctionHandlerAsync(Stream stream, ILambdaContext context)
{
      RootObject rootObj = DeserializeStream(stream);
      User user = new User(rootObj.userName, rootObj.request.password);

      ApiResponse apiResponse = await MobileAuthenticateAsync(user.UserName, user.Password);

    // Considering apiResponse returns "user authenticated", we create the user in //cognito. This is working.

    // How do I send response back to Application so it knows that user is // //created and authenticated and should be allowed to login.

    //Before returning stream, I am setting following 2 status.

     rootObj.response.finalUserStatus = "CONFIRMED"; // is this correct ?
     rootObj.response.messageAction = "SUPPRESS";

     return SerializeToStream(rootObj);;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty close.

You can see the full documentation on the [Migrate User Lambda Trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-migrate-user.html) page, however in short you need your response to look like:

```
{
  response: {
    userAttributes: {
      email: 'user@example.com',
      email_verified: true,
      custom:myAttribute: 123,
    },
    finalUserStatus: 'CONFIRMED',
    messageAction: 'SUPPRESS',
    forceAliasCreation: false,
  }
}
```

Where:

- `userAttribute`: this is a dictionary/map of the user's attributes keys in cognito (note that any custom attributes need to be prefixed with `custom:`), to the values from the system you're migrating from. You do not need to provide all of these, although if you're using an email alias you may want to set `email_verified: true` to prevent the user having to re-verify their e-mail address.
- `finalUserStatus`: if you set this to `CONFIRMED` then the user will not have to re-confirm their email address/phone number, which is probably a sensible default. If you are concerned that the password is given as plain-text to cognito this first-time, you can instead use `RESET_REQUIRED` to force them to change their password on first sign-in.
- `messageAction`: should probably be `SUPPRESS` unless you want to send them a welcome email on migration.
- `forceAliasCreation`: is important only if you're using email aliases, as it stops users who manage to sign-up into cognito being replaced on migration.

If you respond with this (keeping the rest of the original `rootObj` is convenient but not required then the user will migrated with attributes as specified.

If you `throw` (or fail to respond with the correct event shape) then the migration lambda fails and the user is told that they couldn't migrated. For example, because they do not exist in your old user database, or they haven't provided the right credentials.

Comment: I already followed the approach and was able to migrate the user. The problem I am facing is that once the user is migrated, how do I tell my Login API that user exists and should be allowed to login. How do I send Response object back to Login API that exists in AWS API Gateway ?

Comment: UserMigration is only triggered _if_ a user attempts to sign-in that is not listed in Cognito. If they're already in Cognito then the UserMigration lambda isn't triggered (they sign-in using Cognito).

Comment: May be I will try to explain again. Let's say the user do not exists in cognito but do exists in exiting db . the user come to application and try to login. The application calls Login API  (AWS API Gateway)   and since the user is not in cognito, the lambda is triggered and user is migrated. Now how do we send response from lambda back to Login API,  so that API lets user login in usual way (looking at cognito db). Please let me know if that explanation helps ?

Comment: No worries- maybe outline the steps you want to happen against the steps that are happening?

Comment: This is the response object that I am returning from lambda. How do I receive it back at calling application ?                                                "response": {
        "userAttributes": {
            "email_verified": "true",
            "custom:suffix": "Sr"
        },
        "forceAliasCreation": null,
        "finalUserStatus": "CONFIRMED",
        "messageAction": "SUPPRESS",
        "desiredDeliveryMediums": null
    }